# Tratar datos de un archivo plano

Tags: excel

Estoy realizando una actividad que consiste que lo siguiente: tengo una lista de datos en un texto plano de la siguiente manera:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero comparar los datos despues de la segunda coma, si el dato es un numero tengo que moverlo despues del tercer coma, y si el dato es una palabra en este caso es (Conteo 1 Pist.7) no haré nada.

Estoy probando con esto pero no me sale, agradeceria mucho su ayuda. Lo estoy haciendo con VBA desde Excel...

```
Sub leerArchivoTexto()
'Leer archivos de texto separados por coma
'
Dim archivo As String  'ruta y nombre del archivo
Dim texto As String    'línea de texto a leer


Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim renglon As Integer
Dim columna As Integer
Dim contador As Integer
Dim texto2 As String


contador = 0
'Abrir el archivo
archivo = "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Pistolas\conteo1Pistola7_mal.txt"
Open archivo For Input As #1

'Leer y procesar el contenido del archivo
While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, texto

    texto2 = Trim(Mid(texto, 35, 6))


    If (texto2 <> "Conteo") Then
        contador = contador + 1
    End If



Wend
MsgBox (contador)

Close #1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He econtrado la solucion y aca lo comparto por si alguien le sirve en algún momento.
Basicamente lo que hice es obtener cadenas con numero de caracteres especificos usando la funcion Mid de VBA, comparar los valores y en caso de obtener un número volver a armar la cadena y en caso de que sea texto volver a esctribir la cadena tal como está. al final escribo todo en en nuevo archivo para no alterar el original.

```
Open Ruta1 For Input As #1
    Open Ruta2 For Output As #2
        While Not EOF(1) 'Recorrer los registros del archivo original
            Line Input #1, Texto

            texto2 = Trim(Mid(Texto, 35, 6))    'Obtengo el inicio despues de la segunda coma

            If texto2 <> "Conteo" Then
            Else
               conteo_pistola = Mid(Texto, 35, 16)
            End If

            If texto2 <> "Conteo" Then
                texto3 = Mid(Texto, 35, 5)
                cadena = Mid(Texto, 1, 16) & "," 'Armar la cadena.
                cadena = cadena & Mid(Texto, 18, 16) & ","
                cadena = cadena & conteo_pistola & ","
                cadena = cadena & texto3 & ","
                cadena = cadena & Mid(Texto, 58, 1) & ","
                cadena = cadena & Mid(Texto, 60, 16) & ","
                cadena = cadena & Mid(Texto, 77, 10) & ","
                cadena = cadena & Mid(Texto, 88, 8)
                Print #2, cadena 'Escribir en el 2do archivo la nueva cadena
                Cont = Cont + 1
                Else
                cadena = Texto
                Print #2, cadena 'Escribir en el 2do archivo la nueva cadena
            End If

        Wend
    Close #2
Close #1
```